# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax-error

Whats the error in this thing -:

`var decodeChars:Vector.<int> = new <int>[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1];`

I get four complier errors three saying that "1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program." and the fourth saying that "1100: Syntax error: XML does not have matching begin and end tags.".

Whats the actual problem? thanks for help

Comment: that code is not your issue. you are missing a"}", or")", or you have an open string somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be properly formed as demonstrated at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#Vector()

1:  Turn on debugging mode before compiling (Publish Settings > Flash > Permit debugging).  From the errors given, It doesn't sound like this line is the cause of the issue.  Debugging mode will tell you which line is throwing errors.

2:  As The_asMan already mentioned, 1084 is indicating that you have a shortage of close braces.  Make sure you properly indent your code, and this issue should be apparant.

3:  1100 is indicating that an XML file you loaded is malformed.  Run your XML through a syntax validator such as http://validator.w3.org/