# Odd 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a help. It is about rightbrace. Seems there is a problem. I don't know where is the mistake as previous code does not have a problem, but then latter there is a problem. With 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.

```
if (counterEnergy == 1){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(2)
            }
            else if (counterEnergy == 2){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(2)
            }
            else if (counterEnergy == 3){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(2)
            }
            else if (counterEnergy == 4){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(2)
            }
            else if (counterEnergy == 5){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(1)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(1)
            }
            else if (counterEnergy == 0){
                energyFlame1.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame2.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame3.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame4.gotoAndStop(2)
                energyFlame5.gotoAndStop(2)
            }
```

Comment: You are missing ` }` somewhere. I don't see missing in this chunk so it is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Can you give more context? Maybe show more of your code?

Comment: It is all of it. I added a second } down below the first one then it vanished from the error listing, but after that it tells that there is a extra character in errors. In frames before it does not show up.

Comment: And there was a gap line after  }  and else if 4, but even with out it still the same problem exist in the error list.

Comment: I don't know but I'd have a semi colon `;` at the end of each line like `gotoAndStop(1);`.  I have no idea if that will help but please try that.

Comment: You say this is your whole code. It clearly submit your whole code. This alone won't do anything. Yeah your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program. - AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569406/1084-syntax-error-expecting-rightbrace-before-end-of-program-as3)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake's sake, make your code simpler...

```
var EA:Array = [energyFlame1,energyFlame2,energyFlame3,energyFlame4,energyFlame5];

for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var EFi:MovieClip = EA[i];
    EFi.gotoAndStop((i >= counterEnergy)? 2: 1);
}
```